# Simple Work Flow (SWF) Workflow with Spring without xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

Currently I am working on the spring annotation based dependency injection for Activity Worker and Workflow worker As per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/test.html).I have defined my beans inside my spring boot application. Each worker is defined in the separate maven module. The issue that I am facing is that when while running my ActivityWorker spring boot module it stays active and start looking up the activities but workflow worker stops immediately after starting the module with the message '

> Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

My implementation are as following:

```
@Activities(version = "2.2")
@ActivityRegistrationOptions(defaultTaskScheduleToStartTimeoutSeconds = 300, defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds = 100)

public interface TempActivities {
    public GreetWrapper getName();
    public void say(String what);
    /* public Integer doProcess();
    public int sum(Integer num);*/
}

public class TempActivitiesImpl implements TempActivities {
    GreetWrapper greetObj = new GreetWrapper();
    public TempActivitiesImpl() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public GreetWrapper getName() {
        greetObj.setGreet("World");
        return greetObj;
    }

    @Override
    public void say(String what) {
        System.out.println(what);
    }
}
@Workflow(dataConverter = GreetWrapper.class)
@WorkflowRegistrationOptions(defaultExecutionStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds = 3600)
public interface TempWorkflow {
    @Execute(name = "TempWorkflow", version = "2.2")
    public void greet();
}
public class TempWorkflowImpl implements TempWorkflow {

    private TempActivitiesClient activitiesClientImpl = new TempActivitiesClientImpl();
    private DecisionContextProvider contextProvider = new DecisionContextProviderImpl();

    private WorkflowClock clock
        = contextProvider.getDecisionContext().getWorkflowClock();
    @Override
    public void greet() {
        greet1(0);
    }

    public void greet1(int count,
        Promise < ? > ...waitFor) {
        if (count == 3) {
            return;
        }
        Promise < GreetWrapper > name = activitiesClientImpl.getName();
        Promise < String > greeting = getGreeting(name);
        activitiesClientImpl.say(greeting);
        Promise < Void > timer = clock.createTimer(30);
        greet1(count + 1, timer);
    }
    @Asynchronous
    public Promise < String > getGreeting(Promise < GreetWrapper > name) {
        String greeting = "Hello " + name.get().getGreet();
        System.out.println("Greeting: " + greeting);
        return Promise.asPromise(greeting);
    }
}
```

Here is my Activity Worker beans

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    public String getActivityTasklistName() {
        return "HelloWorldTaskList";
    }

    public String getDomainName() {
        return "helloWorldWalkthrough2";
    }

    public String getWorkflowTasklistName() {
        return "HelloWorldWorkflow";
    }
    public String getEndPoint() {
        String endPoint = "https://swf.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
        return endPoint;
    }
    String swfAccessId = System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID");
    String swfSecretKey = System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY");

    /*@Autowired
    TempActivities tempActivitiesImpl;
    @Autowired
    TempWorkflow tempWorkflowImpl; */
    @Bean
    public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
        ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
        config.withSocketTimeout(70 * 1000);
        return config;
    }
    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials() {
        BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(swfAccessId, swfSecretKey);
        return basicAWSCredentials;
    }
    @Bean
    public AmazonSimpleWorkflow amazonSimpleWorkflowClient() {
        AmazonSimpleWorkflow amazonSimpleWorkflowClient = new AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient(basicAWSCredentials(), clientConfiguration());
        amazonSimpleWorkflowClient.setEndpoint(getEndPoint());
        return amazonSimpleWorkflowClient;
    }
    @Bean
    public TempActivitiesClient tempActivitiesClient() {
        TempActivitiesClient tempActivitiesClient = new TempActivitiesClientImpl();
        return tempActivitiesClient;
    }
    @Bean
    public SpringActivityWorker springActivityWorker() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
        SpringActivityWorker activityWorker = new SpringActivityWorker(amazonSimpleWorkflowClient(), getDomainName(), getWorkflowTasklistName());

        activityWorker.addActivitiesImplementation(new TempActivitiesImpl());
        return activityWorker;
    }
}
```

Here is my workflow worker beans

```
public class WorkFlowAppConfig {

    public String getActivityTasklistName() {
        return "HelloWorldTaskList";
    }

    public String getDomainName() {
        return "helloWorldWalkthrough2";
    }

    public String getWorkflowTasklistName() {
        return "HelloWorldWorkflow";
    }
    public String getEndPoint() {
        String endPoint = "https://swf.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
        return endPoint;
    }
    String swfAccessId = System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID");
    String swfSecretKey = System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY");

    /*@Autowired
    TempActivities tempActivitiesImpl;*/
    @Autowired
    TempWorkflow tempWorkflowImpl;
    @Bean
    @Scope("workflow")
    public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
        ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
        config.withSocketTimeout(70 * 1000);
        return config;
    }
    @Bean
    @Scope("workflow")
    public AWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials() {
        BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(swfAccessId, swfSecretKey);
        return basicAWSCredentials;
    }
    @Bean
    @Scope("workflow")
    public AmazonSimpleWorkflow amazonSimpleWorkflowClient() {
        AmazonSimpleWorkflow amazonSimpleWorkflowClient = new AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient(basicAWSCredentials(), clientConfiguration());
        amazonSimpleWorkflowClient.setEndpoint(getEndPoint());
        return amazonSimpleWorkflowClient;
    }
    @Bean
    @Scope("workflow")
    public TempActivitiesClient activitiesClientImpl() {
        return new TempActivitiesClientImpl();
    }
    @Bean
    @Scope("workflow")
    public SpringWorkflowWorker springWorkflowWorker() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        SpringWorkflowWorker workflowWorker = new SpringWorkflowWorker(amazonSimpleWorkflowClient(), getDomainName(), getWorkflowTasklistName());

        workflowWorker.addWorkflowImplementation(tempWorkflowImpl);
        workflowWorker.setRegisterDomain(true);
        // workflowWorker.setDomainRetentionPeriodInDays(1);
        return workflowWorker;
    }
    @Bean
    public CustomScopeConfigurer customScope() {
        CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
        Map < String, Object > workflowScope = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
        workflowScope.put("workflow", new WorkflowScope());
        configurer.setScopes(workflowScope);

        return configurer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?